# Find the number I/O shortest algorithm

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

Find the shortest function/algorithm to translate these numbers to the ones after the dash:

```
0 - 0
1 - 10
2 - 20
3 - 30
4 - 40
5 - 50
6 - 60
7 - 70
8 - 80
9 - 90
10 - 100
11 - 115
12 - 130
13 - 150
14 - 175
15 - 200
16 - 230
17 - 260
18 - 300
19 - 350
20 - 400
```

Every integer higher than 20 is calculated by subtracting 10, calculating the corresponding number like done above and then multiplying that by 4.

Some examples (input will be between []):

```
[10] -> 100
[17] -> 260
[21] -> 4*115 -> 460
[32] -> 4*[22] -> 4*(4*130)) -> 2080
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=80271,OVERRIDE_USER=53878;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Nice first challenge!

Comment: "Java answers are preferred?" D:

Comment: Some people just wanna watch the world burn.

Comment: To OP: [I see what you did there...](http://oeis.org/A120679)

Comment: @KennyLau I fail to see the relevance of that sequence.

Comment: This is a set of numbers someone gave me to implement as strenght to capacity for a hero in an rpg game, this way it is ballanced well, there is no mathematical sequence thats why I wanna see if anyone on here can come up with a good solution to this :)

Comment: @BaldBantha Any other language is accepted though

Comment: @orlp Please refer to my answer.

Comment: @SamApostel does input have to be in brackets? My answer is the only one that takes it that way.

Comment: @BaldBantha no sorry that was just to make the input clear in the question :)

Comment: While cleverly disguised as a question and answer site, we hold programming contests with *objective* winning criteria here. For code golf, that means *shortest code in bytes*, so please don't accept an arbitrary answer just because it uses a particular language.

Comment: This seems less like a codegolf quesiton, and more of a homework/"how can I accomplish this in code" question.

Comment: sorry @Dennis, I removed my answer vote. For me that was the answer because I was looking for a java solution and that was the shortest and only one

Comment: @Zymus do you really think I don't know how to use a simple switch statement? :) I was just looking for someone who could make my code les bulkier and I found these persons over here :)

Comment: @SamApostel While code golf may give you "less bulky" code it also give you literally unmaintainable and slow code because the sole purpose is to write it as short as possible with no concern for legibility or speed.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>64</s> 51 bytes

```
f=n=>n>15?f(n-5)*2:n<11?n*10:f(n-1)+5*"22344"[n-11]
```

Much simpler now that I'm also using @xnor's observation.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 57 bytes

```
lambda n:5*[2*n,4**(n/10-1)*ord('♥♥♥♥#(.4<F'[n%10])][n>9]
```

Replace the four hearts with the ASCII characters 20 (`^T`), 23 (`^W`), 26 (`^Z`), and 30 (`^^`).

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3, 45 bytes

```python
lambda n:[16*n,b'(.4<F'[n%5]<<n//5][n>9]//8*5
```

Sticking to printable ASCII and int output. Uses that the values double every 5 steps, which can be computed with a bit shift.

```python
10 - 100
11 - 115
12 - 130
13 - 150
14 - 175

15 - 200
16 - 230
17 - 260
18 - 300
19 - 350
```

So, for `n>9`, the output is `[20,23,26,30,35][n%5]<<n/5-2`. These values are doubled and packed in a printable ASCII bytearray. The `-2` in the bit shift is pushed to the outside to avoid a negative shift error when `n<=9` -- this is an ugly hack that can probably be handled better.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>93</s> 89 bytes

```java
int f(int n){String x="!$(-28>FP";return n<11?n*10:n<20?(x.charAt(n-11)-10)*5:f(n-10)*4;}
```

A translation of the [answer in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80274/48934) combined with the [answer in C++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80277/48934), also inspired by [this answer in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80298/48934).

### Full program:

```java
public class Q80271 {
    int f(int n){String x="!$(-28>FP";return n<11?n*10:n<20?(x.charAt(n-11)-10)*5:f(n-10)*4;}
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] testcases = new int[]{
            0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
            10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
            20,21,32
        };
        for(int i=0;i<testcases.length;i++){
            System.out.println(new Q80271().f(testcases[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

### Output:

```java
0
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
115
130
150
175
200
230
260
300
350
400
460
2080
```

Comment: DANG! way to go java.

Comment: Also, it's funny that we came up with nearly the *exact* same code and I didn't look at yours.

Comment: @BaldBantha Because we both copied the C++ answer?

Comment: No, my lookup table is different. Technically, you are beating me, but If I use a more convenient input format than the one the OP said than I am 2 bytes shorter. Will golf later.

Comment: I copied the lookup table from the Python answer.

Comment: I think you can save 1 byte by doing `x.charAt(n-11)*5-50` instead

Comment: you can save 10 bytes by inlining the string.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>47</s> 46 bytes

1 byte deletion inspired by [Python's deletion of the final item in the lookup table](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80274/48934).

```
J9L?gb20*4y-bT+?>bT*5@.u+NYj6045983J1-bhT0*Tby
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J9L%3Fgb20*4y-bT%2B%3F%3EbT*5%40.u%2BNYj6045983J1-bhT0*Tby&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19%0A20%0A21%0A32&debug=0)

#### Principle

The lookup table I built is `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 8]`.

If we start from `1`, and then add cumulatively that table:

```
1                   = 1
1+1                 = 2
1+1+2               = 4
1+1+2+3             = 7
1+1+2+3+3           = 10
1+1+2+3+3+4         = 14
1+1+2+3+3+4+4       = 18
1+1+2+3+3+4+4+6     = 24
1+1+2+3+3+4+4+6+8   = 32
```

### Previous 53-byte solution:

```
L?tb+ytbeSmlf!%ydTSydStb1L?>b20*4'-bT+?>bT*5y-bT0*Tb'
```

This needs to be golf... very further. Maybe it would cost less to build a lookup table directly.

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3Ftb%2BytbeSmlf!%25ydTSydStb1L%3F%3Eb20*4%27-bT%2B%3F%3EbT*5y-bT0*Tb%27&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19%0A20%0A21%0A32&debug=0)

#### Principle

If we subtract ten times the first number from the second number:

```
115-110 = 5   = 5*1
130-120 = 10  = 5*2
150-130 = 20  = 5*4
175-140 = 35  = 5*7
200-150 = 50  = 5*10
230-160 = 70  = 5*14
260-170 = 90  = 5*18
300-180 = 120 = 5*24
350-190 = 160 = 5*32
400-200 = 200 = 5*40
```

It corresponds with [A120679](http://oeis.org/A120679): `1,2,4,7,10,14,18,24,32,40,...`

Comment: Genius, now I'll have to convert this principle into java, wish me luck 

Comment: It is probably shorter to directly build a look-up table. I'll write an answer in Java though.

Comment: You're on to something verry amazing 

Comment: Input not like OP said, must be enclosed in brackets. Great program though!

Comment: how on earth did u find this relation for a pseudo-random sequence-progress ?

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 101 bytes

```
function f($i){$a=array(23,26,30,35,40,46,52,60,70);return $i<11?$i*10:$i<20?$a[$i-11]*5:f($i-10)*4;}
```

Huzzah for nested conditional operator!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>32</s> <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ị“.4<F(”Oæ«Ḥ:¥:⁴×µ×>?⁵
```

Uses the astute observation from [@xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80324), which saved 8 bytes.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4buL4oCcLjQ8RijigJ1Pw6bCq-G4pDrCpTrigbTDl8K1w5c-P-KBtQ&input=&args=MzI) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4buL4oCcLjQ8RijigJ1Pw6bCq-G4pDrCpTrigbTDl8K1w5c-P-KBtQowcjIxOzMywrXFvMOH4oKsRw&input=).

#### How it works

```
ị“.4<F(”Oæ«Ḥ:¥:⁴×µ×>?⁵  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

                   >?⁵  If n is greater than 10:
                 µ   ⁵    Execute the chain to µ's left dyadically, with arguments
                          n (left) and 10 (right).
 “.4<F(”                    Yield the string of code points [46, 52, 60, 70, 40].
ị                           Retrieve the character at index n.
                            Indexing is modular and 1-based, so 1, 6, 11, etc. map
                            to the first character, 0, 5, 10, etc. to the last.
        O                   Ordinal; yield the code point of the character.
             ¥              Combine the two links to the left into a dyadic chain.
           Ḥ                  Yield 2n.
            :                 Divide 2n by 10, flooring the result.
                            This yields n : 5 (integer division).
         æ«                 Shift the code point n : 5 bits to the left.
              :⁴            Divide the result by 16.
                ×           Multiply the result by 10.
                        Else:
                  ×  ⁵    Multiply n by 10.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 81 bytes

```
f=lambda n:n>19and 4*f(n-10)or n>10and[23,26,30,35,40,46,52,60,70][n-11]*5or 10*n
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++11, <s>104</s> <s>95</s> 91 bytes

```
int f(int n){int x={23,26,30,35,40,46,52,60,70};return n<11?n*10:n<20?x[n-11]*5:f(n-10)*4;}
```

Simple lookup table and ternary operator fun.

[edit]Thanks!
[edit2]I'm feeling extra stoopid today. Thanks again!

Comment: You can shorten the lookup table if you divide every element by 5 and then multiply it back after indexing.

Comment: You could also chop off the last item in your lookup table and set the threshold to `n<20`, just like what [Python](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80274/48934) did.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 62 bytes

```
i->' '<i?l(i-10)*4:10*i+")*+-037;AIQ".charAt(i>9?i-10:0)%41*5
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6, <s>104 103 100 97</s> 93 bytes

```
 h=a=>{return a<11?a*10:a<20?a*10+c[a-11][1/2,1,2,7/2,5,7,9,12,16]*10:4*h(a-10);},u=p=>h(p[0])
```

usage: call `u` with the input **enclosed in brackets like the OP said.** Will golf later.

## 84 bytes if input is not enclosed in brackets and `h()` is called directly

thanks to kenny lau -6 bytes

Comment: @KennyLau var is required by babel, what do you run it in? es6 is not supported by apple safari

Comment: `s/c[a-11][1/2,1,2,7/2,5,7,9,12,16]/[1/2,1,2,7/2,5,7,9,12,16][a-11]/g`

Comment: java is shorter, you're doing something wrong

Comment: For example: you don't need the ; and you can leave out the return statement, if you use 1-liner lambdas

Answer (score 0):

## Jelly, 42 bytes

```
7568b3+\+\
_⁵ị¢×5+×⁵$
Çµ_⁵ß4×µ20>$?×⁵$>⁵$?
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=NzU2OGIzK1wrXApf4oG14buLwqLDlzUrw5figbUkCsOHwrVf4oG1w580w5fCtTIwPiQ_w5figbUkPuKBtSQ_&input=&args=MzI)

[Test suite.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=NzU2OGIzK1wrXApf4oG14buLwqLDlzUrw5figbUkCsOHwrVf4oG1w580w5fCtTIwPiQ_w5figbUkPuKBtSQ_CsOH4oKs&input=&args=MCwxLDIsMyw0LDUsNiw3LDgsOSwxMCwxMSwxMiwxMywxNCwxNSwxNiwxNywxOCwxOSwyMCwyMSwzMg)

Uses the same principle as my [answer in Pyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80275/48934), just that the array is further reduced to `[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2]`, which can generate `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 8]`, which can generate `[1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 14, 18, 24, 32]`.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, <s>71</s> 66 bytes

```
h n|n<11=n*10|n<20=sum$5<$['.'.."DGKPU[ais"!!(n-11)]|1<2=4*h(n-10)
```

Usage example: `h 32` -> `2080`.

The Haskell version of the algorithm found in many other answers. The results in the middle part for the numbers `11..19` are encoded as strings of consecutive ASCII characters:

```
11:   from . to D  (23 chars)
12:   from . to G  (26 chars)
13:   from . to K  (30 chars)
...
```

Every character in the string is mapped to a 5 and summed up.

Edit: @Lynn helped saving 4 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: `f n|n<11=n*10|n<20=5*length['.'.."DGKPU[ais"!!(n-11)]|1<2=4*f(n-10)` is 4 bytes shorter.

Comment: @Lynn: Nice. I managed to squeeze out one further byte by mapping the string to `const 5` and taking the sum.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot about `<$`! Nice job! ^^

Answer (score 0):

## Julia 0.4, <s>49</s> 42 bytes

```julia
n->n>9?5Int("(.4<F"[n%5+1])*2^(n÷5)/8:10n
```

Uses the astute observation from [@xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80324), which saved 7 bytes. [Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=ZiA9IG4tPm4-OT81SW50KCIoLjQ8RiJbbiU1KzFdKSoyXihuw7c1KS84OjEwbgoKZm9yIG4gaW4gWzA6MjE7MzJdCiAgICBwcmludGxuKG4sICIgLT4gIiwgZihuKSkKZW5k&input=)

---

## Julia 0.3, 38 bytes

```julia
n->2.5max("(.4<F"[n%5+1]<<(n÷5-2),4n)
```

This requires a call to `Int` in Julia 0.4, which makes it longer than the other approach.